# I'm getting this error when installing noodle.js

Tags: node.js, npm, web-scraping, npm-install

```
npm WARN deprecated connect@2.3.9: connect 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.7.0: the module is now available as 'css select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm ERR! path F:\Bot\NewChatbot\node_modules\noodlejs
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! git F:\Bot\NewChatbot\node_modules\noodlejs: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     F:\Bot\NewChatbot\node_modules\noodlejs
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.
```

I tried a lot searching what's the problem , this is a previos posts about the same problem but the answer isn't working

I don't know what does that mean

I already tried:

```
1) npm install dharmafly/noodle
2) git clone https://github.com/dharmafly/noodle.git
3) npm install noodlejs
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt like that you have a git submodule. In your case .git in noodlejs.
So go to your proeject folder and navigate to noodlejs(F:\Bot\NewChatbot\node_modules\noodlejs) and copy .git to your desktop, then install the npm package in your project and then go paste the .git in noodlejsback.

Comment: although I closed this project for a while and kinda forgot why I wanted noodle for in my project but it's not in node_modules to do what you suggest

[image of modules I have](https://imgur.com/a9xngaQ)

Comment: Ah i see! 
Hmm.. I had a similar problem and this solved it for me.. have you tried? otherwise im sorry i dont know the answer :/